# Swift: Split first name and last name from full name string

Tags: ios, swift, split

How to split full name into first and last name. Though I have done following code, is there any better way considering the below values of `fullName`?

Full name can have any of these values:

```
let fullName:String! //(No first or last name)
let fullName = "" //(No first or last name)
let fullName = "Micky" //(fName = Micky, no lName)
let fullName = "Micky Arthur" //(fName = Micky, lName = Arther)
let fullName = "Micky Arthur Test" //(fName = Micky, lName = Arther Test)
```

My Code:

```
if let fullName = name{
   let nameParts = fullName(separatedBy: " ")
   if nameParts.count > 0{
      let fName = nameParts[0]
      var lName = ""
      if nameParts.count > 1{
          for i in 1 ..< nameParts.count{
          lName = lName + nameParts[i] + " "
      }
   }
   print("First Name: \(fName) Last Name: \(lName)")
}
```

Comment: just let fName = parts.removeFirst(), then lName will be the remaining of the array joined with " "

Comment: Keep in mind that any attempt to split a name like this will not work for all cases. A name with only one part could be just a last name. A name might have more than 3 parts. There are first and last names that have more than one part. And the rules could be different for different languages.

Comment: @rmaddy, I see. Is there any algorithm for it?

Comment: if you're on iOS10, you can try using NSPersonNameComponentsFormatter.personNameComponents(from: String). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter/1642979-personnamecomponents

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using this code

```
    let fullName = "testing abducio medina"
    var components = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    if components.count > 0 {
     let firstName = components.removeFirst()
     let lastName = components.joined(separator: " ")
     debugPrint(firstName)
     debugPrint(lastName)
    }
```

Comment: Yes, better than mine. :) Lets wait for even better, otherwise it's an accepted answer..

Comment: @ChanchalRaj ok, seems fair enough to me

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
struct Name {
    let first: String
    let last: String

    init(first: String, last: String) {
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }
}

extension Name {
    init(fullName: String) {
        var names = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let first = names.removeFirst()
        let last = names.joined(separator: " ")
        self.init(first: first, last: last)
    }
}

extension Name: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "\(first) \(last)" }
}
```

#### Usage (e.g. Playground)

```
func testName(fullName: String) {
    let name = Name(fullName: fullName)
    print(name.first)
    print(name.last)
    print(name)
}

testName(fullName: "Jane Doe Foo")
//prints
// Jane
// Doe Foo
// Jane Doe Foe


testName(fullName: "John Doe")
//prints
// John
// Doe
// Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 4):

​​​​Simple solution and fewer lines:

```
let firstName = name.components(separatedBy: "")[0]
let secondName = name.components(separatedBy: "")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 func splitContactFullName(name: String?) -> (firstName: String?, lastName: String?) {
    let namePieces = name?.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let firstName = namePieces?[0]
    var lastName = ""
    if (namePieces?.count ?? 0) > 1 {
        lastName = namePieces?[1] ?? ""
        for i in 2..<(namePieces?.count ?? 0) {
            lastName += " \(namePieces?[i] ?? "")"
        }
    }
    return (firstName, lastName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some thing like this

```
var Name = "first name"
var fullNameArr = split(fullName) {$0 == " "}
var firstName: String = fullNameArr[0]
let middlename: String = fullNameArr.indices.contains(2)? fullNameArr[1] : ""
if fullNameArr.count > 1 {
     var lastName: String? = fullNameArr.last

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func parseName(_ fullName: String) -> (String, String) {
    let components = fullName.characters.split(separator: " ", maxSplits: 1).map(String.init)
    return (components.first ?? "", components.count > 1 ? components.last! :  "")
}
let (fName, lName) = parseName("Micky Arthur Test")
print("First Name: \(fName) Last Name: \(lName)")
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to get the first and last name.

```
let fullName = "Micky Arthur Test"
let nameComponents = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

To be safe use below approach :-

```
let firstName = nameComponents.first , let lastName = nameComponents.last 
print("First name is " ,nameComponents.first ?? "" , ", " , "Last name is " ,nameComponents.last ?? "") 
Output :- "First name is  Micky ,  Last name is  Test"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let fullName = "testing  Arthur "
var components = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
if let index = fullName.firstIndex(of: " ") {
    debugPrint("First Name is \(fullName[fullName.startIndex..<index])")
     debugPrint("Last Name is \(fullName[index..<fullName.endIndex].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))")
}
```